# Jayway JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am using a library which in turn is using Jayway JSONPath. I'm properly referencing a jsonpath `$.location.city` for the following JSON file.

```
{
  "venue":
  {
    "latitude": "51.0500000",
    "longitude": "3.7166700"
  },
  "location":
  {
    "continent": " EU",
    "country": "BE",
    "city": "Brussels"
 }
}
```

But I am getting the error `"InvalidPathException com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['location']for $.location.city"`. Is there any problem with the JSON path ?

Comment: `System.out.println(JsonPath.read(Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(json), "$.location.city").toString());` => `"Brussels"` ... works for me. (I used: `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0`)

Comment: Works for me as well (in case you were wondering :)

Comment: Perhaps it's not reading this json but another which doesn't have "location" in it?

Comment: Looks like your root is the location object and not the entire JSON response you shared.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jayway json-path library
List cityname = JsonPath.parse(response).read("$.location.city");

apply hamcrest matchers it should work