# Issue with JsonPath while extracting field from a json string in Scala

Tags: scala, jsonpath

I have a json string and I want to extract a parameter from this json using JsonPath in scala. Given Json:

```
{
    "message_version":"2.0",
    "message":"1.0",
    "message_metadata":{
        \"event_type\":\"MerchantRegistrationFraudEvaluation\",
        \"event_date\":\"1513665186657\"
        }
}
```

When I tried the below code to extract "event_type" from this json string and it throws an exception:

```
val eventType = JsonPath.read[String](jsonString, "$.message_metadata.event_type")
```

Exception:

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object with property ['event_type'] in path $['message_metadata'] but found 'java.lang.String'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'
```

But if I use two separate statements, one to extract message_metadata first then other one to extract event_type as below it works fine:

```
val eventMetaData = JsonPath.read[String](message, "$.message_metadata")  val eventType = JsonPath.read[String](eventMetaData, "$.event_type") eventType // MerchantRegistrationFraudEvaluation.
```

Can someone help here to get the event_type in a single line?

Comment: It seems similar try to check if you have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698868/jayway-jsonpath

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a specific parameter from a json string using JsonPath in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085463/get-a-specific-parameter-from-a-json-string-using-jsonpath-in-scala)